# Transaction not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

My SQL code is:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO utente(nomeutente) VALUES('pippobaudo');
INSERT INTO fonti(id_fonte, id_esame) VALUES (4, 28);
COMMIT;
```

The first `INSERT`  is correct, but the second is NOT CORRECT because I want to test the transaction. MySQL understands and generates an error in the second INSERT, but incredibly does not respect the transaction and inserts "pippobaudo" in my db.

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Are your tables MyISAM? Does the `COMMIT` get executed?

Comment: Yes my tebles are MyISAM ! I dont understands your second question

Comment: You've tagged this as PHP. Could you add the PHP code you're using, too, please?

Comment: sorry i removed the tag

Answer (score 5):

The MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Oh my Good || How you suggeste to solve my problem ?

Comment: Use an engine that supports transactions: InnoDB. It's the default in latest releases.

Answer (score -1):

ADD IGNORE to INSERT which forces an warning to be generated instead of an error in the transaction.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
INSERT IGNORE INTO utente(nomeutente) VALUES('pippobaudo');
INSERT IGNORE INTO fonti(id_fonte, id_esame) VALUES (4, 28);
COMMIT;
```

note: MyISAM can be done in transactions, but its not a full implementation meaning you cannot undo changes (ROLLBACK)